# How to automate data extraction from Elasticsearch Dev Tools?

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, automation, extract

I have to do the following steps two or three times a day

1. log in into Elasticsearch
2. Go to Dev Tools
3. Run a specific query by selecting it and pressing ctrl + enter
   [Query that I have to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OSbk.png)
4. Select the results that returns in the "buckets" and copy it.
   [The yellow markdown in the image is what I have to select and copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgclj.png)
5. Then I go to https://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm and paste the results so it converts to CSV.
   [Where I have to paste the results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsXXp.png)
6. I can then download the CSV and then import it into google sheets so I can view the results in a Looker Dashboard.
   [Button to download the converted CSV.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Woim4.png)

This take me some time everyday and I would like if there is any way that I could automate such routine.

Maybe some ETL tool that can perform at least part of the process or may some more specific way to do it with python.

Thanks in advance.

I don't have much experience with what I want to do and I tried to search online similar issues, but couldn't really find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you tried, but there is a reporting tool on elasticsearch inside the "Stack Management > Reporting". On the other side, there are another tools which you can work from a server with crontab. Here are some of them :

1. A little bit old but I think it can work for you. [ES2CSV](https://github.com/taraslayshchuk/es2csv). YOu can check there are examples inside the [docs](https://github.com/taraslayshchuk/es2csv/blob/master/docs/EXAMPLES.rst) folder. YOu can send queries via file and report to CSV.
2. Another option which is my preference too. You can use pandas library of python. YOu can write a script according to [this article](https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/export-elasticsearch-documents-as-csv-html-and-json-files-in-python-using-pandas-348), and you can get a csv export CSV. The article I mentioned is really explained in a great way.
3. Another alternative [a library](https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-dataformat) written in Java. But the documentation is a little bit weak.
4. Another alternative for python library can be [elasticsearch-tocsv](https://github.com/fabiopipitone/elasticsearch-tocsv). This one is a little bit recently updated when I compare it to first alternative. But the query samples are a little bit weak. But there is a detailed [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/elasticsearch-to-csv-export-made-easy-python-fabio-pipitone/). You can check it.
5. You can use [elasticdump](https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump), which is written on NodeJS and a great tool to report data from elasticsearch. And there is a CSV export option. You can see examples on GitHub page.

I will try to find more and I will update this answer time by time. Thanks!